# How do I make an agent stop accompanying an army?

Tags: rome-2-total-war

Does anyone know how do I order some of my agents to stop accompanying an army? I hope it's possible because I really need to deploy my champion to improve the happiness in the region.

Comment: Select your army, choose the "agents" tab, right click somewhere else? That's how it worked in *Rome Total War* and in *Total War Shogun 2* at least...

Comment: hes just between the rest of the army, no agents tab.....

Comment: Well click on him in the rest of the army, and right click to another spot to get him out.

Comment: Lyrion, I believe how that's how it works please post it as an answer :)

Comment: I accidentally disbanded my Agent as I thought that it would make him stop accompanying my army. Luckily he was only 1 star, but still annoying.

Answer (score 1):

Select your general and click on the armies list.

Click on the agent, the agent is always the last unit card in your army list.

Right click anywhere on the map. This should make him leave the the army.